# Flutter NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null only on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter

I am developing a huge app and it works perfectly on android when I run it on emulator or real device it works without any errors today I tried to run it on iOS device and emulator and I keep getting a weird error without trace to the location of the error.

> Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone Xʀ in debug mode...
>   Finished with error: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null.
>   Receiver: null
>   Tried calling: length

[Picture of the error [click here]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZgeN.png)

main.dart file :

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
// This widget is the root of your application.
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return  MaterialApp(

  title: 'Flutter Demo',
  theme: ThemeData(

    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
  ),

  home: home_main(),
  routes: {
    // When navigating to the "/" route, build the FirstScreen     widget.
    // When navigating to the "/second" route, build the SecondScreen     widget.
    '/home_screen': (context) => home_screen(),
    '/register': (context) => register(),

    '/tyres':(context)=> tyres(),
    '/walk_through':(context)=> WalkthroughScreen(),
    '/use_my_location':(context)=> UseMyLocation(),
    '/home_main': (context) => home_main(),
    '/main_screen':(context)=> main_screen(),
    '/washing':(context) => maintenance(),
    '/profile':(context) => profile(),
    '/notifications':(context) => notifications(),
    '/cars':(context) => cars(),
    '/orders':(context) => orders(),
    '/aboutus':(context) => about_us(),
    '/testing':(context) => CustomRadio()
  },

);
}
}
```

Comment: please put some code of your implementation where you are getting the error.

Comment: that's the issue there is no track to where the issue is only that error the app has more than 100 dart files and modules

Comment: Can you share your main.dart file at least

Comment: yes I will share It

Comment: add some code on home_main()